# NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish, noclassdeffounderror, opensaml

I'm developing an Identity Provider using OpenSAML API.

I have created a java application to test OpenSAML API which was a success.

The problem is now I'm trying to use that java Application in Servlet using glassfish and I'm loosing my mind right now.

Hear me out:
before you can start using OpenSAML you have to call it's bootstrap to initiate it's components, one of those components is 
    org.apache.xml.security.Init

so i added xmlsec.jar into libraries but every time I run the WebApplication it keeps on getting an exception:

```
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.xml.security.Init"
```

the confusing part is if I remove the xmlsec.jar from libs, it still knows the

```
import "org.apache.xml.security.Init"
```

but when I delete that and try to rewrite the same:

```
import "org.apache.xml.security.Init"
```

now it fails because now org.apache doesn't have xml.security in it.

any idea guys?

PS: I'm using these:
                   - NetBeans IDE
                   - Glassfish 4.1.1
                   - Java EE 7
                   - JDK 1.8

glassfish output:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[LoginServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet LoginServlet threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.xml.security.Init
at org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.initializeXMLSecurity(DefaultBootstrap.java:195)
at org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap(DefaultBootstrap.java:98)
at opensamltest1.SAMLHelper.printSAMLObject(SAMLHelper.java:180)
at LoginServlet.processRequest(LoginServlet.java:53)
at LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:100)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: A `NoClassDefFoundError` with the message 'Could not initialize class SomeClass` means that the JVM has already tried and failed to load the class `SomeClass`.  Restart GlassFish and try again, and hopefully you should get a different exception (possibly an `ExceptionInInitializerError`).  If so, edit your question to include the stacktrace of that exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you should abandon glassfish and go to JBoss.
That solved my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This could be due to a conflict between classes provided by JVM or your Container host, and those in the WAR file.  If the class is duplicated in both places it can play all sorts of havoc with your startup.